# why double Sigma summation?

Tags: summation, notation

The lecture slides is about covariance. One page it is
[image]

on the other page, it is

[image: second notation]

Why there are double Sigma summation on the first one?Is it just a typo?

Comment: It is simply notation. There is a double summation. One for all the $x$ and one for all the $y$.

Comment: It is a typo. One can either use one summation sign indexed by $(x,y)$ or two summation signs indexed by $x$ and by $y$ respectively, but mixing these two options is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

I think a very clear definition of covariance is:

$Cov(X,Y) = \sum\limits_{x \in X}\sum\limits_{y \in Y} (x- \mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f(x,y)$

If you define $S = X \times Y = \{(x,y) | x \in X, y \in Y\}$ (cartesian product).

Then you can rewrite the definition as:

$Cov(X,Y) = \sum\limits_{(x,y) \in S} (x- \mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f(x,y)$

I think the first equation in your post is a confusion between the two definitions written in this answer.
It is not even clear to me what summation sign $(x,y) \in S$ belongs to.
However, a lot of notation abuse like this is made, **if** it is clear what is being meant. Which was obviously not the case here since you were confused.

Answer (score -1):

It is a double summation, one over $x$ and one over $y$, so strictly speaking you need two $\Sigma$ signs on both slides.

Sometimes people leave only one just for easier notation.

Comment: "strictly speaking you need two Σ signs" No, see comment.

Comment: $(x,y) \in S$ is only one element. So I would argue only one summation sign is needed. A summation over all $(x,y) \in S$.